# CSS - animate icon to 'rotate' upon the dropdown of a menu on wordpress site

Tags: css, wordpress, nav

I have a wordpress site, http://watershedgeo.staging.wpengine.com/#, and I'm using a theme and it's built in nav menu.

I have modified it to use font awesome icons after the menu items that have dropdown items. I'm using the right angle, >, but I'd like to use a plugin or css to animate this so that when the dropdown comes down the icon rotates to 'V'.

I'd like to not have to build any JS into this and I know it can be done with CSS I'm just not sure of the best way to do this that also works well in the WP environment.

Current CSS:

```
.fusion-megamenu-icon {
display: inline;
margin-left: 12px;
float: right;
}


.fusion-megamenu-icon:hover {
transform: rotate(90deg);
}
```

Comment: have you tried transform on .current-menu-item icon ? such as : `.current-menu-item .fa.glyphicon.fa-angle-right {
    transform: rotate(90deg);
}` give a try on hover too

Comment: Sorry, I updated with my current CSS and that does work when I hover over only the icon. Is there a way for this to work if I hover over the menu item in general though?

Comment: yes, look at html structure and update the selector with the right class. My example uses the CSS applied to the list item of the current page. (li:hover  icon) select the parent

Comment: I'm not exactly sure what you mean? I tried this but it's still on icon hover, not menu item hover 

.menu-item:hover .fusion-megamenu-icon:hover{
transform: rotate(90deg);
}

Comment: :hover is to be used on parent only. You should learn some basics about styling, it will be helpfull You can start here https://stackoverflow.com/tags/css/info ;)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add Some Custom CSS to your Code

Try This

CSS

```
ul.fusion-menu > li.menu-item-has-children:hover a i.fa{
  transform:rotate(90deg);
}
```

Comment: no need to involved a new class and js there. wordpress uses its own class and update them for each page requested where needed ;)